# best double value limit in c++

Tags: c++, double, limit

I am working with matrices in c++ and the type of elements is double. My limit for matrix dimentions is 10,000. I want to know what is the logical value to set as limit for elements, considering the fact that I am doing many sum and multiplication actions on them. I want this number to be as high as possible but without having infinity number problems.

Comment: Why do you think you need to "set a limit for the elements" at all?

Comment: I mean, you are already limited by your system architecture for indexing into your matrix. Isn't that enough?

Comment: i get infinity in the result of matrix product.

Comment: It's likely you are doing something (logically or technically, like dividing by 0, using uninitialized automatic variables) wrong. An upper limit will likely not help you. For one, how do you want to decide whether your result exceeds it?

Comment: In order to help you we need more information. Best would be to reproduce the errors in a small piece of code which you can post here. Often the error becomes visible to oneself in the process of preparing that minimal example...

Comment: Show us a [MCVE].

Answer (score 1):

The range of double is

```
1.7976931348623158e+308
```

Lets say maximum value of element as X;
for multiplication the maximum answer will be

`X*X + X*X + X*X .....10,000 times(maximum row and column count)`

i.e

`10000*X*X`

Therefore
`

```
1.7976931348623158e+308  = 10000*X*X

1.7976931348623158e+304 = X*X

X ~ 1.7976931348623158e+150
```

But you will lose precision.

This value is if you are going to multiply once.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use [`std::numeric_limits`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/limits/numeric_limits/).

---

For example:

```
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
          std::cout << "float\t"
          << std::numeric_limits<float>::lowest() << '\t'
          << std::numeric_limits<float>::max() << '\n';
          std::cout << "double\t"
          << std::numeric_limits<double>::lowest() << '\t'
          << std::numeric_limits<double>::max() << '\n';
}
```

Comment: How does this answer the op's question?

Comment: @George Errr... like, she asks for a limit, and Mohamed provides one? (Admittedly the question is not entirely clear -- other people seem to think she's asking for a limit on indexes, not values. But given that she is doing "many sums and multiplications" on them and talks about infinity results, I think she's asking for element value limits.)

Comment: Question "I want to know what is the logical value to set as limit for elements", and the elements are `double` so this should be what the max and min limits of a `double` on a given machine.

Comment: The question isn't what the max and min values of double are. It's about what (smaller) limit to use for doubles. But the question is poorly specified since it isn't clear what the purpose of the limit is.

Comment: @interjay yes, I suggest using these values ...

Comment: That makes no sense. These values are already the maximum and minimum possible `double`s, so using them as a limit will do nothing.

Comment: @interjay Given zero value constraints -- and infinity results --, the logical limit *is* the  technical limit. Given the (poor) quality of the question I would be astonished if the OP knew about `std::numeric`.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider The OP is asking about which value constraints to use to avoid infinity results. This can't really be answered though without knowing the exact operations that will be performed. In any case, this answer does not answer the question at all.

Comment: @interjay based on my interpretation, on a scale of min to max the OP can represent the numeric values.

Comment: So you're saying he can represent numeric values by using values in the entire range of numeric values? That's not really saying anything useful. And it doesn't answer the OP's question about how to avoid infinite results from calculations.

Comment: No, I mean something like `saturate_cast` in opencv http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/utility_and_system_functions_and_macros.html

Comment: `saturate_cast` from what type to what type? OP is using `double`s. What are you suggesting they do exactly? What should they do with `std::numeric_limits<double>::max()`?

Comment: to set INF to `std::numeric_limits<double>::max()` if that is the limit OP asks for

Comment: @MohamedMoanis To be honest the op's question should be closed as too broad. Reading it, it seems like they want to limit the individual elements in order to prevent anything being evaluated to inf, the problem is that there's no context and no reason given as to why this is necessary(which is required to give a good answer) as alluded to by the first comment on the op's question.

Comment: @George I agree with you.